# Why django showing 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

'function' object has no attribute 'objects' is being shown when I try to fetch objects from database

I was following code with harry playlist on django ,and trying to fetch product from database [my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu2El.png).I have created 3 products in admin panel. I saw some solutions to my problem ,where the problem was solved by changing the function name. But my problem seems to be different.
this is my models.py
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5cOx.png)

function in view.py where I make the call....error showing on the line7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EipA1.png)

trying to render it in html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZcAi.png)

Comment: please share the code instead Screenshots. and can you confirm is there any function defined with name `product`?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Heman patel............click on the blue links ....the images will appear..........its my first time using stackoverflow ,sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: yes i checked that. is there any function defined with name `product`? and refer this from next time. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @HemalPatel no the function name is index.

Comment: can you share that whole file? just use this ``` put your code here and close ```. edit the question.

Comment: @HemalPatel https://github.com/Deeproychaudhury/DEmo i have uploaded the files here for your reference

Answer (score 1):

just rename this function

```
def product(request):
      return HttpResponse("Product")
```

You're calling the above function instead model in this code block

```
def index(request):
    productobject=product.objects.all()
    print(productobject)
    
    return render(request,'shop/index.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you say function name its already 'index' check whether there may be another one overlapping, best way to prove this is adding an identifier to the model import like this:

```
from .models import product as ProductModel

def index(request):
    productobject=ProductModel.objects.all()
    print(productobject)
    
    return render(request,'shop/index.html')
```